# Saving and restoring Queue Manager

Tags: ibm-mq

I need to install a fresh copy of Websphere MQ Server on a Windows machine.

However, the queue manager and other details need to be migrated from the Websphere MQ Server which is in place on another system.

Of what I could gather from my excavations from the internet is that there exists a support pac(MS03) from IBM which provides with the functionality. The executable being `saveqmgr.exe` for MQ versions upto 7.0 and dmpmqcfg for MQ 7.1 on Windows platform.

My question is: what should be the command that should be run to secure the details of the queue manager?

Also,after getting the required information in a file how do I use `runmqsc` command to restore all the definitions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

The following command can be used to backup the queue manager config using saveqmgr (MS03 Support Pac) to a file:
`saveqmgr -m QUEUE_MANAGER -f BACKUP_FILE`

The following command can be used to backup the queue manager config using dmpmqcfg in version 7.1 and higher to a file:
`dmpmqcfg -m QUEUE_MANAGER > BACKUP_FILE`

The following command can be used to restore the queue manager config using runmqsc:
`runmqsc QUEUE_MANAGER < BACKUP_FILE`

For the above `QUEUE_MANAGER` is the name of the queue manager you want to backup/restore and `BACKUP_FILE` is the name of the text file containing the backup.

Comment: In addition to capturing and restoring the objects, a full backup/restore also includes exits, ini files, queue tuning settings, environment variable settings, HA configurations, and certificates.  Not all of these are present on every node but all need to be captured and restored if present.  Note that for some of these like log files, it isn't sufficient to restore the ini file.  The size of the log extent files must be set when the QMgr is first defined.